# ¿Como insertar varios datos en una columna en los seeders con laravel?

Tags: laravel, array, seeders

Buenas, en esta ocasión necesito saber como insertar multiples datos en una sola columna de mi tabla desde los seeders o factory en laravel.

La cuestion es que tengo una tabla llamada institutos que tiene 4 campos, tiene 'id' , 'institutos' , 'created_at', 'updated_at' . Yo solo quiero agregar los valores al campo 'institutos' ya que los demas se llenan automaticamente, pero cuando lo hago desde el array en seeder, al ejecutarlo en consola me muestra este error: A four digit year could not be found Data missing.

Esto es lo que he intentado en el seeder:

> Instituto::create(array(
>               'institutos' => 'data 1', 'data 2 ', 'data 3', 'data 4'
>           ));

¿Alguna solución?...

Comment: Quieres guardar un array en el campo institutos o quieres crear 4 registros con los datos del array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método create espera una array con `clave => valor` para cada campo. Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras, por ejemplo:

```
Instituto::create(['institutos' => 'data 1']);
Instituto::create(['institutos' => 'data 2']);
//...
```

O guardando el array en una variable e iterar sobre ella (a mi personalmente no me parece buena práctica hacer una query dentro de un loop, pero si no son muchos datos funciona bien):

```
$data = [
        ['institutos' => 'data 1'],
        ['institutos' => 'data 2']
];

foreach ($data as $instituto) {
    Instituto::create($instituto);
}
```

Otra forma sería usando el método insert:

```
$data = [
            ['institutos' => 'data 1'],
            ['institutos' => 'data 2']
    ];


DB::table('institutos')->insert($data); // cambia institutos por el nombre de la tabla
```

Comment: Tu segunda opcion me sirvió amigo gracias.. excelente